# Trying to use a list box to select multiple emails and send a PDF with a button click in Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I was able to select 1 email address with a combo box but I haven't had much luck with a list box. The problem I'm trying to solve is to have a list of email addresses, select a few and send the email (a report) with a button click.

```
DoCmd.SendObject acReport, "Report", "PDFFormat(*.pdf)", Forms!LNGF!List93, "", "", "Report", "", False, ""
```

is the code I have right now. Doesn't work. Keep getting error message "An expression you entered is the wrong data type for one of the arguments"

The code that works is:

```
DoCmd.SendObject acReport, "Report", "PDFFormat(*.pdf)", Forms!LNGF!Combo86, "", "", "Report", "", False, ""
```

As you can see, the only thing that has changed is switching from a list box to a combobox. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Just before that runs, put in a messagebox with the value of Forms!LNGF!List93 and Forms!LNGF!Combo86.  See what happens.  My bet is that the data types are gonna be different, as the error message indicates.

Comment: check the following properties: "bound column", "Multiple selection", "Columns count"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have more than one item selected in your listbox then you would need to run the Send Object code several times within a loop. The loop should iterate through the selected items in the listbox.

Code to accomplish this would look similar to the following:

```
Dim control As Access.control
Set control = Forms!LNGF!List93
Dim varItem As Variant
For Each varItem In control.ItemsSelected
    DoCmd.SendObject acReport, "Report", "PDFFormat(*.pdf)", control.Column(1, varItem), "", "", "Report"
Next
```

Alternatively you could loop through each selected item and build a string with the email's delimited by a ;

Comment: This gets me close. Now it just pulls up the email client (Outlook) and attaches the file but won't fill in the "To" field.

Comment: AhHa! Changed the above code with `control.Column(0, varItem)` and it worked. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Glad I could be of use.